# Advice - How To Start Converting Video / Audio

Tags: ogg

I have been using C++ for the last five years now.  During this time, I never had to work with audio nor video files.  One thing I want to write is an application that will take a AVI/MPEG file and convert it to the OGG format.

Are there any good books / tutorials out there where I can get my feet wet in this domain in general?  I am aware the [Xiph.Org Foundation](http://www.xiph.org/), the group responsible for OGG, have libraries and documentation for their API.

Thanks for any insight provided.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) source code?

Comment: Thanks for the idea!! I never thought of looking at source code of a particular multi-media format to learn overall how things work.